# Python "Multi-Level Decorator" - how does this work?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have been writing some functions for database operations in a script and decided to use a function decorator to handle the db connection boilerplate.

A stripped down example is shown below.

### Function decorator:

```
import random

class funcdec(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.state = random.random()
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.func(self.state,*args,**kwargs)

@funcdec
def function1(state,arg1,**kwargs):
    print(state)

@funcdec
def function2(state,arg2,**kwargs):
    print(state)

function1(10)
function2(20)
```

This means I can reduce the amount of boilerplate but I have a different state object per function.  So if I run this I get something like:

```
python decf.py 
0.0513280070328
0.372581711374
```

I wanted to implement a method for making this state shared by all the decorated functions and I came up with this.

## Decorated Function decorator:

```
import random

class globaldec(object):
    def __init__(self,func):
        self.state = random.random()

    def __call__(self,func,*args,**kwargs):
        def wrapped(*args,**kawrgs):
            return func(self.state,*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapped

@globaldec
class funcdec(object):
    pass

@funcdec
def function1(state,arg1,**kwargs):
    print(state)

@funcdec
def function2(state,arg2,**kwargs):
    print(state)

function1(10)
function2(20)
```

Now when I run this the state object is only created once per application and the state is the same for all decorated functions e.g.:

```
python decg.py 
0.489779827086
0.489779827086
```

Intuitively this makes sense to me because the `globaldec` is only initialised once for all instances of the function decorator.

However, I am a little bit hazy on exactly what is going on here, and that fact that the `funcdec` object appears to not be initialised or called anymore.

## Questions:

1. Does this technique have a name?
2. Can anyone shed some more light on what is going on internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a *decorator factory*; a callable object that produces a decorator. In this case you are *ignoring* the `func` argument to `globaldec.__init__()` (the original `funcdec` class object) when using the `globaldec` class as a decorator. You instead replaced it with an instance of the `globaldec` class, which is then used as the real decorator for `function1` and `function2`.

That's because decorators are just syntactic sugar; the `@globaldec` decorator applied to the `class funcdec:` line can be expressed like this:

```
class funcdec(object):
    pass
funcdec = globaldec(funcdec)
```

so `funcdec` the class was replaced by an instance of `globaldec` instead.

Instead of using classes, I'd use functions; state like `func` and `state` become closures.

Your original decorator then can be written like this:

```
import random

def funcdec(func):
    state = random.random()    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(state, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

So when Python applies this as a decorator, `funcdec()` returns the `wrapper` function, replacing the original `function1` or `function2` functions are replaced by that function object. Calling `wrapper()` then in turn calls the original function object via the `func` closure.

The `globaldec` version just adds another layer; the outer function produces the decorator, moving the closure out one step:

```
import random

def globaldec():
    state = random.random()    
    def funcdec(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(state, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return funcdec
```

Just create the decorator once:

```
funcdec = globaldec()

@funcdec
def function1(state,arg1,**kwargs):
    print(state)

@funcdec
def function2(state,arg2,**kwargs):
    print(state)
```

An alternative pattern would be to store the state as a global (you could do so directly on the decorator function:

```
import random

def funcdec(func):
    if not hasattr(funcdec, 'state'):
        # an attribute on a global function is also 'global':
        funcdec.state = random.random()
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(funcdec.state, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Now you no longer need to produce a dedicated decorator object, the `wrapper` now refers to `funcdec.state` as the shared value.